# OData client $expand does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Software used:

- ASP.Net Web Api 2
- OData v4
- Microsoft OData Client 6.13

Consider the following Model:

> Location (Id, LocationName, Street, PostalCodeId)
>
> PostalCode (Id, ZIP)

A *Location* has one *PostalCode* and a *PostalCode* has many *Locations*.

This is the OData-Configuration:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Location>("Locations");
builder.EntitySet<PostalCode>("PostalCodes");

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Model classes:

```
public class Location {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String LocationName { get; set; }
    public String Street { get; set; }
    public int PostalCodeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PostalCodeId")]
    public PostalCode PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class PostalCode {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

When calling `http://localhost:49938/odata/Locations?$expand=PostalCode&$orderby=LocationName` in a browser **$expand** works:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost:49938/odata/$metadata#Locations",
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "LocationName": "My Location 1",
      "Street": "Street 7",
      "PostalCodeId": 1838,
      "PostalCode": {
        "Id": 1838,
        "ZIP": "4081"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I do the same request in the application, it does not work:

```
Container c = new Container(new Uri("http://localhost:49938/odata/"));
var result = c.Locations
                 .Expand(x => x.PostalCode)
                 .OrderBy(x => x.LocationName)
                 .ToList();
```

When I execute this code `PostalCode` is `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Martinaut

Is there any query operation between `new Container...` and `var result= ...`?

If yes, please add the following codes:

```
container.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Thanks.